# Regex Checks for semi colon (;)

Tags: regex

I have a set of value to extract but some may be followed by a semicolon and some do not. Tried `(.*)\;?` but it seems like they extract the semicolon as well. I only want the value to be extracted.

Value 1: Xfdagb;
Value 2: Gegshb

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `([^;]*)\;?`

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Then why have `;?` at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex `(.*)\;?` matches any character zero or more times followed by an optional semicolon.

The `.*` is greedy and matches until the end of the line. Then it tries to match a semicolon which is optional so the whole line stays matched.

If you want to extract `Value 1: Xfdagb` and `Value 2: Gegshb` you might use a negating [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match not a semicolon one or more times:

[`[^;]+`](https://regex101.com/r/aGFSt6/2)

If you want to extract the values `Xfdagb` and  `Gegshb` you might use a negated character class and capture the values in a capturing group:

[`[^:]+: ([^;]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/aGFSt6/1)